# Hola No consigo actualizar los items de mi carrito, creo que el error esta en price y quantity

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    Aqui el codigo html que he estructurado con sus tags,
se que el fallo esta donde estoy apuntado en price y en quantity pero le lanzo
```

console.log y no se a donde tengo que apuntar para que me almacene esos valores,
quizas pasandolo con un parseInt, cualquier ayuda me seria super util y la daria como
ok rapidamente,si hay algo que tengo mal montado tiene que ser en el archivo js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
        <title>e-commerce</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>e-commerce</h1>
        <table id="cart">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Product Name</th>
              <th>Unit Price</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Subtotal</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="product">
              <td class="name">
                <span>Rubber Duck</span>
              </td>
              <td class="price">$<span>25.00</span></td>
              <td class="quantity">
                <input type="number" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Quantity" />
              </td>
              <td class="subtotal">$<span>0</span></td>
              <td class="action">
                <button class="btn btn-remove">Remove</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <p class="calculate-total">
          <button id="calculate" class="btn btn-success">Calculate Prices</button>
        </p>
        <h2 id="total-value">Total: $<span>0</span></h2>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    
    Aqui el codigo js que estoy montando, la idea es que cuando le doy a precio y 
    cantidad me muestre el subtotal de esos productos

    function updateSubtotal(product) {
    
      const price = product.querySelector('.price span')
      price.innerHTML = 25
      const quantity = product.querySelector('.quantity')
      quantity.innerHTML = 2
    
      const subtotal = product.querySelector('.subtotal')
      subtotal.innerHTML = price * quantity
    
    }
    
    function calculateAll() {
      
      const singleProduct = document.querySelector('.product');
      updateSubtotal(singleProduct);
```

se que el fallo esta donde estoy apuntado en price y en quantity pero le lanzo console.log y no se a donde tengo que apuntar para que me almacene esos valores, quizas pasandolo con un parseInt, cualquier ayuda me seria super util y la daria como ok rapidamente,si hay algo que tengo mal montado tiene que ser en el archivo js

Answer (score 0):

al final consegui la solucción, la dejo por aquí por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda

```
function updateSubtotal(product) {

  const price = product.querySelector('.price span')
  const priceElement = parseInt(price.innerText)

  const quantity = product.querySelector('.i').value
  let quantityElement = quantity

  let subtotal = product.querySelector('.subtotal span')
  subtotal.innerText = priceElement * quantityElement

}
```